# Trigger on DB make problem on wordpress?

Tags: posts, database

If i insert a trigger for wp_posts table, wordpress make me impossible to publish posts,forums,articles.

And get error: "You don't have permission for publish".

How it should bee(it's without trigger on db)
[image: how it should bee]

Error below:
[image]

[image]

trigger code:
`CREATE TRIGGER added_new_forum 
  AFTER INSERT ON wp_posts FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF(post_type='forum' AND post_status='publish') THEN 
     INSERT INTO wp_posts(ID,post_author,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_content,post_title,post_excerpt,post_status,comment_status,ping_status,post_password,post_name,to_ping,pinged,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_content_filtered,post_parent,guid,menu_order,post_type,post_mime_type,comment_count) VALUES(NEW.ID+5,NEW.post_author,NEW.post_date,NEW.post_date_gmt,NEW.post_content,NEW.post_title,NEW.post_excerpt,NEW.post_status,NEW.comment_status,NEW.ping_status,NEW.post_password,NEW.post_name,NEW.to_ping,NEW.pinged,NEW.post_modified,NEW.post_modified_gmt,NEW.post_content_filtered,NEW.post_parent,NEW.guid,NEW.menu_order,NEW.post_type,NEW.post_mime_type,NEW.comment_count); END IF;`

Comment: how did you added the query?

Comment: Vishwa i just  created the trigger on mysql ...

Comment: can you show the code or how you did it?

Comment: of course added

Comment: Don't do this. Use `add_action()` to use a hook to perform your actions when a post is inserted. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/